# Cannot run Typescript

Tags: typescript, windows

I spent some time trying to solve the issue that caused an error when trying to execute Typescript,I have Node installed and I ran the installation command but I can't run either with Node or with "tsc"

"the file cannot be loaded + path link " and "it is not digitally signed"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpLXI.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Try running it with cmd instead of powershell